OpenCL - how exactly is the kernel-code compiled
Good afternoon!
To use OpenCL, you need to define the context, the device, and compile the kernel from the source code in a .cl file.
If I understand correctly, compilation takes place at this stage
cl::Program program(context, source);
program.build(default_device, "OpenCL_optimization_options_from_specification");

But how exactly does the compilation happen? What compiler is used and can I manually pass compilation flags to it, bypassing the optimization options in the .build() method?
The thing is, none of the options available in the spec can give me what I really need.
I'm using CUDA 12.4 with an RTX 4080, and I assume the nvcc compiler is involved. However, it can't compile .cl files, and when I try compiling the whole program (by passing the -x c++ flag), the flags I specify that control optimizations have absolutely no effect. Apparently, even in this case, the .build() method is called inside the host program, which calls the compiler again with other flags.

OpenCL programs are designed to be device agnostic, so the program that runs on the host is compiled as normal, with appropriate flags for opencl, but there is a runtime compilation of the kernels to run on the OpenCL device or devices selected.

nvcc is to build CUDA programs, not OpenCL one. OpenCL kernels are compiled to PTX at runtime by the vendor-specific OpenCL runtime which is the Nvidia one here. On another device like Intel iGPUs it is not PTX but something else. On Nvidia devices, PTX code is then compiled to native SASS (device specific) at runtime. Note CUDA and OpenCL are competitors though CUDA is only for Nvidia devices while OpenCL is not limited to Nvidia GPUs, but also supports AMD/Intel GPUs and even devices like FPGAs.

@JérômeRichard I don't know how good it is but ZLUDA is supposed to support CUDA on AMD GPUs too, though I think I heard the project is no longer maintained.

@SimonGoater ZLUDA does not fully support CUDA in practice. Libraries like CuBLAS, CuDNN, CuSparse have a very limited support (not supported on Windows and only partially on Linux) and/or bad performance. Advanced applications tend to crash with it, be instable or just slow. This is too experimental yet to be used in production IMHO (a bit like Wine for running Windows apps on Linux). Not to mention the CUDA environment contains also profilers and debuggers which AFAIK not ported, and the fact that CUDA applications will certainly always be optimized for Nvidia GPUs.

@SimonGoater That being said, it is a great project with quite surprising results so far. It seems still actively supported due to the recent release. I hope they will succeed to make to at least stable though this is a huge task. CUDA has become the new standard this last decade and both OpenCL and SYCL unfortunately failed to replace it so far (sad for people having Intel/AMD GPUs).

@Simon, but how exactly does a runtime compilation of the kernels work? Can I control it manually? There is a program.compile() method in <opencl.hpp>, but it seems to ignore my calls, because even if I pass explicitly wrong flags as an argument, no errors occur.

@Jérôme, you say: "On Nvidia devices, PTX code is then compiled to native SASS (device specific) at runtime", but can you tell me how can I interfere with this process?

AFAIK you cannot for SASS and I do not see any reason to do that. For PTX, you can apparently compile OpenCL kernels to PTX using Clang manually. IDK if this helps.
